# select an xml descendants based on a node

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, linq

I have an XML and I want to pick an element based on a date. So Date descendants has list of dates less than today.

XML has values like this

```
<Dates>
<Department>
 <ID>Food</ID>
 <Date>25-11-2016</Date>
</Department>
<Department>
 <ID>Sport</ID>
 <Date>26-10-2016</Date>
</Department>
</Dates>
```

Now I need to pick only the elements where the respective date is less than today and the below query will pick the dates and remove the items from xml.

```
XDocument newXML = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xmlValues));
var q = from node in newXML.Descendants("Date")           
        let attr = node.Value where attr != null && DateTime.ParseExact
        (attr, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) < DateTime.Today    
        select node.Parent;             
q.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());
```

Now how can I pick only the below items which has date less than today?

```
<Department>
 <ID>Sport</ID>
 <Date>26-10-2016</Date>
</Department>
```

Comment: Your query does that already, surely (if you fix `ExpiryDate` to `Date`)? Just don't remove them.

Comment: @CharlesMager - My bad, it was typo. I tried to view it without removing, but couldn't see it though in `q.ToList()`

Comment: As an aside on the removal, you can just do `q.Remove()`.  And use the `XDocument.Parse` overload rather than loading a `StringReader`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
            string xml =
                "<Dates>" +
                    "<Department>" +
                     "<ID>Food</ID>" +
                     "<Date>25-11-2016</Date>" +
                    "</Department>" +
                    "<Department>" +
                     "<ID>Sport</ID>" +
                     "<Date>26-10-2016</Date>" +
                    "</Department>" +
                "</Dates>";

            XElement dates = XElement.Parse(xml);

            List<XElement> departs = dates.Descendants("Department").Where(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.Element("Date").Value, "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) < DateTime.Now).ToList();
```

Comment: How can I check whether this linq has identified the items?

Comment: The results is a list object and you can get the count or length of the list.