# check if linq conditions has results

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, linq

I am making some validations in an xml and remove certain elements based on date fields the below LINQ will do the job just fine.

```
XDocument newXML = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xmlValue));
 var q = from node in newXML.Descendants("Date") let attr = node.Value 
     where attr != null && DateTime.ParseExact (attr, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
     < DateTime.Today select node.Parent; 
 q.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());
```

How can I check whether this linq has identified and removed the items? OR
How can I load the results of newXML as an xml document?

Comment: Duplicate!  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40303047/select-an-xml-descendants-based-on-a-node/40309082#comment67929677_40309082

Comment: @jdweng - Got it!